# PHP Check if current time is before specified time

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to check in PHP if the current time is before 2pm that day.

I've done this with `strtotime` on dates before, however this time it's with a time only, so obviously at 0.00 each day the time will reset, and the boolean will reset from `false` to `true`.

```
if (current_time < 2pm) {
   // do this
}
```

Comment: This is not even valid PHP. What is `current_time`?

Comment: @KingCrunch I believe that's pseudo-code, rather than actual code. :-)

Comment: I know that's not valid PHP, I was just giving an example of the logic.

Comment: Examples are fine, but when solutions depends on concrete formats (`2pm`, `14`, `14:00`, .... ?), then they are not useful.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
if (date('H') < 14) {
   $pre2pm = true;
}
```

For more information about the date function please [see the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). I have used the following time formatter:

> H = 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)

Comment: Good point about minutes not being required.  Mind linking to docs for `'H'`?

Comment: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php Lists all the different ways of formatting the date. Thinking about it could be cleaner to use 'G', as it doesn't include a leading 0 where the hour is only 1 digit, although PHP isn't fussy enough to let that effect the result of the if statement.

Comment: Why H and not G ?

Comment: @Feras - good question! As I answered over 7 years ago I’m not sure why I went for H over G. I don’t think you’d get a different outcome but using a value without a leading 0 would make more sense.

Answer (score 34):

Try:

```
if(date("Hi") < "1400") {
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
i   Minutes with leading zeros                      00 to 59
```

Comment: heh, was going crazy trying to read that with the $ in front. Didn't help that it said 'Hi' ^^

Comment: Should `1400` be a string?

Comment: @user2924019 they will result in the same answer - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php `If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.`. Would you get better performance? I don't know, benchmark it! Is one more clear than the other? It depends on your project/organization's style guidelines and how much you prefer brevity to being explicit. My personal preference these days would be `if((int)date("Hi") < 1400)`, but I don't regularly use PHP.

Answer (score 17):

You could just pass in the time

```
if (time() < strtotime('2 pm')) {
   //not yet 2 pm
}
```

Or pass in the date explicitly as well

```
if (time() < strtotime('2 pm ' . date('d-m-Y'))) {
   //not yet 2 pm
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use 24 hour time to get round the problem like so:

```
$time = 1400;
$current_time = (int) date('Hi');
if($current_time < $time) {
    // do stuff
}
```

So 2PM equates to 14:00 in 24 hour time. If we remove the colon from the time then we can evaluate it as an integer in our comparison.

For more information about the date function please [see the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). I have used the following time formatters:

> H = 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)
>
> i = Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)

Comment: Many years later, it's interesting to note that you don't have to convert a time with colons to an integer. PHP comparison operators are smart enough to know that '13:00' is less than '14:00'!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't told us which version of PHP you're running, although, assuming it's PHP 5.2.2+ than you should be able do it like:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$twoPm = new DateTime();
$twoPm->setTime(14,0); // 2:00 PM
```

then just ask:

```
if ( $now < $twoPm ){ // such comparison exists in PHP >= 5.2.2
    // do this
}
```

**otherwise**, if you're using one of older version (say, 5.0) this should do the trick (and is much simplier):

```
$now = time();
$twoPm = mktime(14); // first argument is HOUR

if ( $now < $twoPm ){
    // do this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether the time is before 2.30 pm ,you can try the following code segment .

```
if (date('H') < 14.30) {
   $pre2pm = true;   
}else{
   $pre2pm = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if( time() < mktime(14, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j"), date("Y")) ) {

// do this

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will check if it's between hours in EST by accepting 2 params, arrays with the hour and am/pm...

```
    /**
     * Check if between hours array(12,'pm'), array(2,'pm')
     */
    function is_between_hours($h1 = array(), $h2 = array())
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
        $est_hour = date('H');

        $h1 = ($h1[1] == 'am') ? $h1[0] : $h1[0]+12;
        $h1 = ($h1 === 24) ? 12 : $h1;

        $h2 = ($h2[1] == 'am') ? $h2[0] : $h2[0]+12;
        $h2 = ($h2 === 24) ? 12 : $h2;

        if ( $est_hour >= $h1 && $est_hour <= ($h2-1) )
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `time()`, `date()` and `strtotime()` functions:

```
if(time() > strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 14:00') {
    //...
}
```