# PHP check if a time is larger then or smaller then a specfic time

Tags: php

I know this question was probably asked,
however i did not find the answer anywhere.

I would like to determine if the current time is before or after 10:30 AM with php. i found a long way to do it that involves a lot of time parsing. but i am sure there are better ways of doing it.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475019/php-check-if-current-time-is-before-specified-time) answer it show how to do it if the hour is a whole number (example 2PM)

```
if( 'now' is larger then 'a given time' ){

}
```

Comment: Did you check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/comparing-two-dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `time()`, `date()` and `strtotime()` functions:

```
if(time() > strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 10:30') {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). But remember it accept date object.

```
if(strtotime(dateobject) > strtotime(dateobject)){
  //
}
```